# import data using custom workflow and action mscrm

Tags: dynamics-crm

Can we import data using custom workflow and action in mscrm?

Is it possible to call action on button click and pass excel sheet as input so that we can read excel and created records according to it.

Comment: Quick question why do you need workflow or action. Crm itself provide excel import option and using that you can either create record or update records. Does out of box excel import not solve your purpose??

Comment: In Excel there will be entity name and specific columns will be mentioned based on that i need to records in multiple entities and need to handle some custom logic while creating records . For this i need to add button on form and show dialog window to select file .For this we achive by attach excel file to some entity and trigger custom workflow amd read data in customflow of that attachment?

Comment: Yes you can do so, you do not need workflow or action for this. Add excel as notes to any entity, when you add excel a note will be created I.e it will give you create plugin message on annotation entity. Get that create message and then use this excel sheet to create records. But my personal opinion stick to out of box excel import and when record is created using excel import on create fire a plugin and update a record. You have 2 above ways. Let me know this helps??

Answer (score 0):

No and No.

I read you are going to get some metadata & data from your import file & custom business logic around the content. OOB import may not be a good fit.

Maybe you can build a custom HTML web resource to parse spreadsheet using [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) & manipulate the data using web api in client side itself or store in Annotation (Notes) itself like Ankuser said to parse in plugin/workflow.